# Data modelling using mongoose for sports bet tracking application

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design

I built a simple sports bet tracker application while I am learning the MERN stack. Users can track their sports bets and see various stats on their performance. It currently only supports tracking single bets (1 selection in bet) and I wish to add to ability to track multiple bets (>1 selections in bet). Each selection in a multiple bet will have the same data as a single bet `eventDate`, `sport`, `event`, `selection` `odds` etc. I'm just looking for some advice on the best way to add this in. Bet model currently is as follows

```
const betSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  eventDate: {
    type: Date
  },
  sport: {
    type: String
  },
  event: {
    type: String
  },
  market: {
    type: String
  },
  selection: {
    type: String
  },
  odds: {
    type: Number
  },
  result: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Pending'
  },
  stake: {
    type: Number
  },
  owner: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'User'
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
})
```

Going forward a bet can have one selection or many in it so I was thinking this should become an array. If it has one selection the odds for the bet will be the odds of that selection but if it has multiple selections in it the odds of the bet will be the odds of the selections multiplied. If one selection in a multiple bet loses the bet is a loss. I was thinking something like the following setup but I'm not sure as I don't have much database experience any help who'd be appreciated.

```
const betSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  selections: [{
    sport: {
      type: String
    },
    event: {
      type: String
    },
    eventDate: {
      type: Date
    },
    market: {
      type: String
    },
    selection: {
      type: String
    },
    result: {
      type: String
    },
    odds: {
      type: Number
    },
  }],
  odds: {
    type: Number
  },
  stake: {
    type: Number
  },
  result: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Pending'
  },
  owner: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'User'
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with the Schema shown in the question, not sure if it's the best solution but it works for what I am trying to build.